# Somar as notas dos alunos em Jquery ou Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou precisando fazer com que, quando o administrador cadastrar as notas dos usuários digitados nos campos Nota1, Nota2, Nota3, Nota4 e Nota5, seja contabilizado os valores individualmente, sendo que, se um deles passar dos 200 pontos, apareça uma mensagem automaticamente informando que o valor superou o valor permitido (200 pontos). A listagem dos usuários está vindo do PHP, vejam:

```
<?php
....
$visualizar = '<table class="table">
                 <thead>
                   <tr>
                     <td>Aluno</td>
                     <td>Nota 1</td>
                     <td>Nota 2</td>
                     <td>Nota 3</td>
                     <td>Nota 4</td>
                     <td>Nota 5</td>
                   <tr>
             <tbody>';
while($pe = mysqli_fetch_object($sql))
{
   $visualizar .= '<tr>';
   $visualizar .= '<td><input type="text" name="Nome[]" class="form-control" value="'.$pe->NomeUsuario.'" readonly></td>'; 
   $visualizar .= '<td><input type="text" name="Nota1[]" class="form-control"></td>';
   $visualizar .= '<td><input type="text" name="Nota2[]" class="form-control"></td>';
   $visualizar .= '<td><input type="text" name="Nota3[]" class="form-control"></td>';
   $visualizar .= '<td><input type="text" name="Nota4[]" class="form-control"></td>';
   $visualizar .= '<td><input type="text" name="Nota5[]" class="form-control"></td>';
}
....
```

É possível fazer isso no Jquery ou Javascript?

Comment: Já tentou `<input type="number" max="200">`?

Comment: Olá Fernando. Seria uma boa opção, porém as notas serão nesse formato: 5.5, 10.0, 3.2, etc. e acredito que, por ser um campo number, não aceite esses formatos.

Comment: É só adicionar `step="0.1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para identificar cada ROW, eu usaria um ID no seus TR, assim você poderia pegar os valores facilmente pelo querySelector, eu também retiraria o [] dos names, isso indica um vetor.

```
var nota1 = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#id input[name=Nota1]").innerText);
// ...
var notaN = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#id input[name=NotaN]").innerText);

//Faria isso até ter todas as notas e então a soma:
var Total = nota1 + nota2 + ... + notaN;
```

Você vai ter que capturar a nota de cada campo, fazer parse pro float e somar.

Sobre a validação de cada campo passar dos 200 você pode usar um listener onChange e verificar se o valor é > 200...

```
var nota1 = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#id input[name=Nota1]").innerText;
if(nota1 > 200) {
    // Use um alert ou algo para avisar
    alert("Valores não podem ser acima de 200");
    document.querySelector("#id input[name=Nota1]").focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Abaixo minha sugestão, comecando com o HTML:

```
<table class="table">
             <thead>
               <tr>
                 <td colspan="2">Aluno</td>
                 <tr>
                  <td>Nota 1</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="nota1" value=""></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td>Nota 2</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="nota2" value=""></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td>Nota 3</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="nota3" value=""></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td>Nota 4</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="nota4" value=""></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td>Nota 5</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="nota5" value=""></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td><button type=button onclick="soma()" >Somar</button></td>
                 </tr>
               <tr>
</table>
<p>Resultado: <span><span></p>
```

No fim do HTML existe um elemento  que vai receber o valor total da soma das notas inseridas no formulário, quando o usuário clica no botão "somar".

Essa estilização abaixo é apenas para visualização:

```
tr{
  display:block;
}

td{
  outline:solid red 1px;
  padding:10px 30px;  
}
```

Finalmente o codigo javascript que vai coletar todas as notas nos inputs, fazer a soma e printar na página o resultado. Caso a soma exceda 200, é printada a frase "Total de valores acima de 200".

```
var nota= document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];

var entrada = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

function soma(){
  total=0;
  for(i=0;i<entrada.length;i++){
    total+=Number(entrada[i].value);
  }
  if(total<=200){
    nota.innerHTML=total;
  } else{  
    nota.innerHTML="Total de notas acima de 200";
  }
}
```

Para visualizar o resultado clique em https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vMKmed